# Can i edit home audio to hear whats going in the background about a loud tv (sensitive subject)

Tags: audio, recording

Is it possible to make make TV quieter and what's going on in the background louder on a audio recording ( sensitive subject)

Comment: This shows absolutely no research. What have you tried so far? Why didn't it work?

Comment: I really have no clue how to do this myself I've spent hours looking online and trying different audio editing apps but without any understanding of the basics I just have no idea what I'm doing.

Comment: There are a number of questions on this exact topic on this site. The basic upshot is: you can't do it well unless you pay for expensive software such as Izotope RX. Check out other questions on noise reduction.

Comment: If you could get the original track of what you watched on the TV, then you could cancel that. But that's close to impossible that way. However, the opposite of noise cancellation could help in your case (i.e. removing the loud audio means keeping the noise).